# Terminal command for gThumb Image Viewer

Tags: gnome-terminal, gthumb

I have these two graphics applications.

In my control panel, their names are listed as  `gThumb` and `Image Viewer`.

`gThumb` has too many features for my taste, so I normally use `Image Viewer`, which displays one image at a time and does not show the directory tree.  Since `Image Viewer` has the same icon and GUI, I think it is just a minimalist version of `gThumb`.

In `Terminal`, `gthumb` is the command for `gThumb`.  What is the command for `Image Viewer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Image Viewer" is also known as "Eye of GNOME", the command is

```
eog
```

Comment: Thanks!  Looks like they were both developed by Free Software Foundation, Inc., which explains the identical GUIs and icons.